# Disable or hide Add button in ASP.Net grid view footer template

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have been searching for a way to hide or disable the Add button in an ASP.Net grid view footer template. I have found lots of articles explaining how to hide the Delete Edit options in the grid view but that is not what I want to do.
The Delete, Edit, and Add all work fine but I need to hide the Add button when the user clicks Edit to edit a row.

How can I do this?

Comment: What does your gridview footer look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to hide another button.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#editButton").click(function () {
    $("#view").hide();
    $("#edit").show();
    $("#cancelButton").show();
    $("#editButton").hide();

});

$("#cancelButton").click(function () {
    $("#edit").hide();
    $("#view").show();
    $("#editButton").show();
    $("#cancelButton").hide();

});
</script>
```